# Is there a practical difference between creating Promises by hand and using the async/await API?

Tags: typescript, async-await, promise

I've inherited a codebase which is full of functions like this:

```
const someFunc = async (): Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const result = await doSomething();
            resolve(result);
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
};
```

It is my understanding that since the error is not handled in the `catch` this is essentially the same as doing this:

```
const someFunc = (): Promise<string> => {
    return doSomething();
};
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: see: [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Answer (score 2):

This is horrible indeed. [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

> Did I miss something?

Synchronous exceptions thrown by `doSomething`. We assume it returns a promise, so this should never happen, but *if* they do, then your code is not strictly equivalent to the original which returns a rejected promise. You'd fix this by simply making it an `async` function:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line require-await -- async is used to catch the synchronous exceptions
const someFunc = async (): Promise<string> => {
//               ^^^^^
    return doSomething();
};
```

If this is not an issue, you could shorten the code even further:

```
const someFunc: () => Promise<string> = doSomething;
```

Comment: I know some linter configurations warn when `async` is used without `await`, and also when `return await ...` is used (which I understand is fundamentally different than `return` when used inside a `try` block in order to catch rejections as well as synchronous errors). Do you recommend just disabling `require-await` in ESlint or do you have a workaround you'd suggest?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts In that case I'd just use `// eslint-disable-next-line require-await -- async is used to catch the synchronous exceptions`. But if `doSomething` is written properly, it won't throw a synchronous exception, so this is not necessary :-)

Comment: I like that, because it emphasizes the fact that the `async` is code-smell because of the sub-par implementation of `doSomething`.